# How to create mysql database and user and grant permissions of this user with dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

Hello all I have tried a lot of stuff but it seems that I'm not able to create database and user with docker file can you please help me I'm trying the following:

RUN sudo yum install mysql-server -y
RUN sudo systemctl enable mysqld
RUN mysql -v -e "create database test;"

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through         
 socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through     
 socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

 The command '/bin/sh -c mysql -v -e "create database test;"' returned 
 a non-zero code: 1 `
```

Can this be achieved with dockerfile without using docker compose?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend using the [Docker Hub `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) instead of trying to roll your own.  You can't create a derived image that has database data or configuration preloaded, but you can put SQL scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` that will get run at first startup, and some very basic configuration can be done with environment variables.

You don't have to use Docker Compose (though it's certainly convenient for basic multi-container setups).  Without Compose, you could start your application and database together like:

```sh
# Create a network so the containers can see each other
docker network create a-network

# Start the database
# (You can also add an option
# -v $PWD/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
# to run ./initdb/setup.sql and similar scripts)
docker run -d \
  --net a-network \
  --name database \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root-password \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test \
  -e MYSQL_USER=test \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=test \
  mysql:8

# Start the application
docker run -d \
  --net a-network \
  --name myapp \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -e MYSQL_HOST=database \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test \
  -e MYSQL_USER=test \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=test \
  myapp:20200809
```

(A `docker-compose.yml` file would look very similar, but would have this in YAML syntax instead of `docker run` commands.)

In the Dockerfile fragment in the question, neither `sudo` nor `systemctl` really work in Docker.  (For `sudo`, there aren't usually user passwords, nor is there an opportunity to type one in a Dockerfile; `systemctl` only works if the `systemd` daemon is running, and it almost never is in a container.)  Each `RUN` command runs in a clean environment, and running processes aren't preserved across `RUN` commands, so your `RUN mysql ...` step isn't running a database that it could attach to.

In principle this is *possible*; you have to start the database server, then run the `mysql` command, then cleanly stop the database, all within the same `RUN` step.  That's kind of tricky; it'd be much easier to configure the standard image.